# How to compare two DataTable and return the diffrence?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

Lets say I have two DataTable dt1 and dt2, I add row to dt1 and do AcceptChanges, and then dt2 = dt1.Copy and continue add row to dt2

Example1:-

```
    dt1                    dt2
    ---------------        ---------------  
    | item  | qty |        | item  | qty |
    ---------------        ---------------
    | Apple |  1  |        | Apple |  1  |
    | Orange|  1  |        | Orange|  1  |
    ---------------        | Banana|  2  |
                           ---------------

Dim dt_compare as DataTable = dt2.GetChanges()

    dt_compare                  
    ---------------       
    | item  | qty |        
    ---------------       
    | Banana|  2  |
    ---------------
```

Above result is what I get, and it is what I want also, but please take a look on Example2

Example2:-

```
    dt1                    dt2
    ---------------        ---------------  
    | item  | qty |        | item  | qty |
    ---------------        ---------------
    | Apple |  1  |        | Apple |  1  |
    | Orange|  1  |        | Orange|  10 |
    ---------------        ---------------

Dim dt_compare as DataTable = dt2.GetChanges()

    dt_compare                  
    ---------------       
    | item  | qty |        
    ---------------       
    | Orange|  10 |
    ---------------
```

If I just change the value it will return the same value when I use GetChanges(). How can I get result 9 instead of 10?

Comment: you're asking for the difference in the quantity? i.e. dt2.qty - dt2.qty? You'd have to do that yourself. GetChanges looks for absolute changes in the data. It says "is there a difference", and then reports yes/no, and lists the changes. It doesn't know what maths you want to do on that data - after all, it's only by chance that the change is even on a numeric field. And then, there could be many different possible calculations to do, how should it know what you need? But it's given you the opportunity - now you know there's a difference, you can do your own calculation to suit yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with `RowVersion` to achive what you want. Basically, you can check if the change has been a modification, and in that case substract the current value from the original. Would be something like this:

```
Dim dat1 As DataTable = New DataTable()
dat1.Columns.Add("item")
dat1.Columns.Add("qty")


dat1.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Apple", 1})
dat1.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Orange", 1})

dat1.AcceptChanges()
dat1.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Banana", 2})
dat1.Rows(1)("qty") = 10

Dim dtChanges As DataTable = dat1.GetChanges()
For Each dr As DataRow In dtChanges.Rows
    If dr.RowState = DataRowState.Modified Then
        dr("qty") = Convert.ToInt16(dr("qty", DataRowVersion.Current)) - Convert.ToInt16(dr("qty", DataRowVersion.Original))

    End If
Next
```

An alternative using Linq:

```
Dim modified = dat1.GetChanges() _ 
                   .AsEnumerable() _ 
                   .Where(Function(x) x.RowState = DataRowState.Modified) _
                   .Select(Function(x) New With {
                     .Key = x("item"),
                     .Value = Convert.ToInt16(x("qty", DataRowVersion.Current)) - Convert.ToInt16(x("qty", DataRowVersion.Original))}) _
                   .ToList()
```